# Swift: How to increment to get images for Collections

Tags: ios, swift, collections, uiimage

Using Swift

I have a collections app to show over hundreds of items. In `cellForItemAt` I'm trying to show images so it matches with the name. For example, my images are called `0_0`, `0_1`, `0_2` to `0_723`, etc. This is the code I have so far but it's not working.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Collections

    // Use arrayCount to for selecting Image | initalized as global as -1
    arrayCounter = arrayCounter + 1
    print(arrayCounter)

    // Set Image
    cell.imageCell.image = UIImage(named: "\(checkGroupChoice)_\(arrayCounter)")

    // Rounded Corners for Image Cell
    cell.imageCell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    cell.imageCell.layer.masksToBounds = true

    return cell
}
```

I thought by doing this since it loops for every cell that I can just increment but what i didn't know is that it only increments to what the screen sees and once you scroll the numbers completely change and images stop showing.

So how can I increment `arrayCount` to the max of `Items.count` so I can use my images to the cells it belongs too.

Comment: Use indexPath as a reference instead.

Comment: Thank you, you can add it as an answer. For some reason I thought I couldn't use it, only when a cell is selected.

Comment: That's not necessary.  Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

The counter does not work, as the cellForRow function is called multiple times, not just once per cell.
What you should use instead is the indexpath of the cell. Specifically the indexpath.item. If you have multiple sections you have to correct it by the number of items in the previous sections.